# Control yaw via Lua-script in Ardupilot

Tags: lua

I make some additions and scripts for Ardupilot. So, I want to control copter yaw via Lua-script. I can do it with `set_target_angle_and_climbrate` method. But I can use this method only in guided mode. This method changes copter submode to angle_control. I need the yaw of the copter to change, but at the same time it remains in the same mode as it was. This should happen if it is in RTL, Guided, Loiter, Auto modes. Is there any other method in Ardupilot that I can transfer to lua, or an existing one in lua that will help me with this?

I tried to use this method but that's not what i need

```
function set_drone_yaw(yaw)
   mode = vehicle:get_mode()
   vehicle:set_mode(COPTER_GUIDED_MODE)
   is_set_yaw = vehicle:set_target_angle_and_climbrate(0, 0, yaw, 0, false, 0)
   vehicle:set_mode(mode)
   return is_set_yaw
end
```